# Controlling swipe inputs in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, swipe

I am practicing in Unity; I want to move an object to the right and left according to how I swipe. I have gotten the script so far but the problem occurs when I am playing it. It is setting the objects location to the center; swipe actions are working just fine. However, I don't want it to set the object to the center.

**Script:**

```cs
public class swipeTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public SwipeManager swipeControls;
    public Transform Player;
    private Vector3 desiredPosition;

    private void Update() {
        if (swipeControls.SwipeLeft)
            desiredPosition += Vector3.left;
        if (swipeControls.SwipeRight)
            desiredPosition += Vector3.right;

        Player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards
            (Player.transform.position, desiredPosition, 0.5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

And Another

```cs
public class SwipeManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
    private bool isDraging = false;
    private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;

    public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
    public bool Tap { get { return tap; } }
    public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
    public bool SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
    public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
    public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }

    private void Update() {

        tap = swipeLeft = swipeRight = swipeUp = swipeDown = false;

        #region Standalone Inputs
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            tap = true;
            isDraging = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            isDraging = false;
            Reset();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Mobile Input
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {
            if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                isDraging = true;
                tap = true;
                startTouch = Input.touches[0].position;
            }
            else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) {
                isDraging = false;
                Reset();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        // Calculate the distance
        swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        if (isDraging) {
            if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
                swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
        }

        //Did we cross the distance?
        if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 125) {
            //Which direction?
            float x = swipeDelta.x;
            float y = swipeDelta.y;
            if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y)) {
                //Left or right
                if (x < 0)
                    swipeLeft = true;
                else
                    swipeRight = true;
            }
            else {
                // Up or down
                if (y < 0)
                    swipeDown = true;
                else
                    swipeUp = true;
            }
            Reset();
        }
    }

    void Reset() {
        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        isDraging = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of think you could precise here: "t is setting the objects location to the center" --> the center of what? screen, parent transform? is it RectTransform? And "I don't want it to set the object to the center" --> so what do you want?

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud yes the center of the screen... i want the object to stay at it's own location and just respond to the swipe event. whenever i start the game it's setting the objects x and y position to center of the screen after that if i am swiping left it's moving left and on right it's moving right. what i just want is to not set the x and y position to 0(center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you never initialised `desiredPosition` in your code.

I did not successfully reproduce your issue, but theoretically I believe this should work. Please let us know if it helped.

Assuming no other forces act on the `Player` tranform (it won't be moved other than by this script):

```
public class swipeTest : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Start() {
        desiredPosition = Player.position;
    }
}
```

Or if other forces act on `Player` you should update it every time:

```
public class swipeTest : MonoBehaviour {


    private void Update() {

    desiredPosition = Player.position;

        if (swipeControls.SwipeLeft)
            desiredPosition += Vector3.left;
        if (swipeControls.SwipeRight)
            desiredPosition += Vector3.right;

        Player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards
            (Player.transform.position, desiredPosition, 0.5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```